# Frame bounds in java

Tags: java, swing

how to set frame bounds in such a way that it occupies the entire region of the window ?
I tried doing

```
Frame f=new Frame();
f.setBounds(0,0,Window.WIDTH,Window.Height)
```

but this code makes the frame go up and i cannot view the title bar..Please help me with this

Comment: whats the `Window`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about emtpy `JFrame` & `Window???`

Comment: its like i want the frame to be of that size which appears when we maximize the frame or window as u say...for e.g.when we click on "My Computer" we get a small window initialy and later when we click on "maximize button" we see the entire "My Computer" frame/window ..I want my frame bounds in such a way that they appeared maximize.its difficult to explain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123735/get-effective-screen-size-from-java
That shows how to get real screen size and subtract taskbar space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Dimension min = new Dimension(500,500);
    frame.setMinimumSize(min);

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension max = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    frame.setMaximumSize(max);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

Try this code . Its works the same way you wrote on comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`setExtendedState (int state)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) with `MAXIMIZED_BOTH` state.

Comment: i tried using this setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); but the frame goes up..i want the frame start from 0,0 pixel..Please can you help me further with this

Comment: What do you mean *"frame goes up"*?

Comment: The frame goes up means i m not able to see the title bar .so when i click at the bottom line of frame then only i m able to drag the frame so that the start location of frame is at 0,0 pixel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Frame f=new Frame();
f.setBounds(0, 0, Window.HEIGHT,Window.WIDTH);
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```