# Java WindowBuilder on different screen resolution

Tags: java, screen-resolution, windowbuilder

I am making a java program for *Windows* with `GUI` using **windowbuilder**.
I set the sizes of the components so that it would match a screen resolution of *3200x1800*.

After I built the program I ran it on a different computer with a screen resolution of *1366x768*. All of the components were much bigger than running the program in the high screen resolution screen.

How can I set the components to be in the same size for all screen resolutions (the components will match the screen resolution)?

Comment: Is this Swing you're using?

Comment: I am using **SWT** windowbuilder

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123735/get-effective-screen-size-from-java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear @amitai you must have to use some layout provided by Java like gridBagLayout, BorderLayout and FlowLayout bla bla bla Adjust your components as per Layout recommendation. If you will success to adjust your components in Layout your problem will automatically solved.

These Layouts are developed for the purpose of adjusting components in a sequences for different type of resolutions. Layout are working as a container.

For brief discussion follow reference link below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html